# How do you handle invalid input if you need the user to enter an integer?

Tags: java, exception, input

I'm trying to write a program that takes user integer inputs and does something with them, and continues to do so until the user enters a non-integer input, at which point the user will no longer be asked for input. This is what I've tried:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Question2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean active = true;
        String num_string_positive = "";
        String num_string_negative = "";
        int my_int;
        while (active) {
            try {
                my_int = in.nextInt();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                active = false;
            }
            in.close(); 
        }
    }

}
```

This doesn't seem to work; there seems to be something wrong with the catch block. When I hover over `IOException`, Eclipse says "Unreachable catch block for IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body". Shouldn't a non-integer input throw an I/O exception when I call the `nextInt()` method?

When I replace `catch(IOException e)` with `catch(Exception e)`, the code does run, but it always terminates after one input, even if the input is an integer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: more likely a NumberFormatException -> I'm wrong here, check the link in my next comment to see which Exceptions and in which case

Comment: `nextInt()` can throw three different `Exception`.  `InputMismatchException`, `NoSuchElementException`, and `IllegalStateException`.  You can see this in its documentation.  `InputMismatchException` is likely the one you are looking for.  Additionally, you should not close your `Scanner` that is using `System.in`, your code will not work.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

Comment: try adding negative if not block to it - I mean to handle the negative case in this case.

Comment: @ManojVayu how would that work? He is catching the wrong exception, and if block won't stop that exception being thrown

Comment: Remove `in.close();` from the body of your loop. Once you close the `Scanner` you also close `System.in`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if the input is not an Integer the exception that will be thrown is `InputMismatchException`, and you shouldn't close the scanner until you continue with it, try this instead:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Question2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean active = true;
        String num_string_positive = "";
        String num_string_negative = "";
        int my_int;
        while (active) {
            try {
                my_int = in.nextInt();
            } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                active = false;
                in.close();
            } 
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
      System.out.println("Input is an integer.");
      sc.nextLine(); //Store this input in an array or variable as per your need.
    }
    int number = sc.nextInt();
  }
```

This code will check if the input is an Integer, if it is then it will continue to take input and as soon as user enters some other value it will stop taking the input.

Comment: your code won't compile, since you use scan, instead of sc in your next call. Also, if the user enters (only) valid input, your code will cause in infinite loop, and won't do as it should. Can you spot why?

Comment: Thanks for reviewing the code error for scan. and his requirement was something like that regarding the input that it should keep on taking input if user puts integer as input. And further anyone can modify this code according to their requirement!

Comment: I actually ran your code, after changing the scan to sc. Have you? As soon as you get out of the loop, it threw an Exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (active) {
    try {
        my_int = in.nextInt();
        active = false;
    } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid input!!");
    }
    in.nextLine();//clear the buffer
}
in.close();
```

1. You should catch the correct exception to process
2. You should terminate the while loop with `false`, only for valid input. What you are trying to do is, you are eliminating when there is a wrong input.
3. Close the scanner post completion of input retrieval

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse rightly recommends that your `catch` block trying to catch an `IOException` is unreachable. This is because none of your code in the corresponding `try` block throws that particular checked exception. All you have in the `try` block is a method call `Scanner#nextInt`. As per the [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) of this method, this method doesn't throw an `IOException`. Instead, it throws the following three exceptions:

- InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer
  regular expression, or is out of range
- NoSuchElementException - if
  input is exhausted
- IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed

So in your case, you should update your `catch` block to catch `InputMismatchException` instead.

An alternate solution to meet your goal is to use `hasNextInt` method instead. It will be much cleaner.

On a side note, you shouldn't close the scanner resource until you are done reading.

```
while (in.hasNextInt()) {   
    my_int = in.nextInt(); 
} 

// close the scanner 
in.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you're doing a few things wrong.  Besides the obvious (you're catching the wrong exception as you figured out), you're not looping properly, and also you can't use `nextInt()`.

Look at your requirements.  You said:

> a program that takes user integer inputs and does something with them, and continues to do so until the user enters a non-integer input, at which point the user will no longer be asked for input.

If you use `nextInt()` how will you find any non-integer input?  Clearly you need to do something else here.

Try to break down the program into smaller chunks.  You could introduce methods to make your job easier and more clear.

```
public class Question2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean active = true;
        String num_string_positive = "";
        String num_string_negative = "";
        int my_int;
        while (active) {

          // Get input
          String input = getInput();

          // Is input integer?
          active = isInteger( input );

          // If integer do something
          if( active ) {
             // something
          }

        }

    }

}
```

If you start by sort of sketching your code out like this, making a sort of outline, then you'll run into fewer problems.  Breaking down your code into smaller chunks makes it easier to read, write and understand and debug.  Basically wins all the way around.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. This code will always read only one input because of the in.close method will always execute inside the while loop. 
In order to close the input only when no integer is read, you have to put it after the while loop and this will execute only when the active flag is false.
On the other hand, you cannot catch IOException because nextInt method does not throw it. To catch a more especific exception than Exception, you have to use InputMismatchException

Comment: Just as an extra note, he really should not close this `Scanner` _at all_.  It was opened using `System.in` which the JVM will close when necessary, but if you close it yourself you will never be able to open it again during the program's execution.  Closing a `Scanner` is when you open a `Scanner` using a `File`.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you! I was trying to find out what error would be thrown but I couldn't figure it out. And thanks Nexevis; I didn't know that either.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
 static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number -> ");
            String input = sc.next();
            int intInputValue = 0;
            try {
                intInputValue = Integer.parseInt(input);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
                System.out.println("This is not a integer");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The program will display " this is not an integer" if user enters an input other than integer.

Comment: But this code just displays the log but, the while loop is executed endlessly.

Comment: There is a break statement also there which will stop the execution of while loop once the user will put integer.

Comment: The needed behavior is to loop until the user enters a non-integer value, but here you are doing the opposite.

Comment: I think the program is now fine after your edit. @M.Ismail